# Xamarin.Forms - Using Grid inside Button

Tags: xamarin.forms, grid

I couldn't find the answer to my question anywhere, so I hope I don't ask something twice.

When I need to divide a ListView cell in my Xamarin.Forms app, I simply use Grid to do that and that works perfectly fine. Now I need to do the same in a Button, but I have no idea how and if this is even possible.

I need to create a grid like this:
[image]

(black contour is the button, red lines are de grid lines)

Is this even possible?
I hope someone can help.

Best

Comment: You can't do this.  You can make a grid behave like a button with a TapGestureRecognizer

Comment: Ah that's a good one! I'll try to figure out how to do that, thanks!